# Error when converting string number to decimal in Crystal Reports: "The string is non-numeric"

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

### Problem description

In my report I get amounts in strings. The formatting is pretty unusual:

1. **""** - is zero amount
2. **"(200.00)"** - is negative amount
3. **"1,234.56"** - is positive amount

I want to convert those strings to numeric values in more convenient way:

1. **0.00**
2. **-200.00**
3. **1234.56**

First I am doing some preformattings of the string amount:

```
local stringvar amount := Trim({PLD__ITEMS.F_18});

if amount = ''
    then amount := '0.00'
;

amount := Replace(amount, "(", "-");
amount := Replace(amount, ")", "");
amount := Replace(amount, ",", "");
amount := Replace(amount, " ", "");
```

Then I wanted to convert string into number using **ToNumber** or **CDbl** methods, but both result with the same error

```
// "The string is non-numeric"
//ToNumber(amount)

// "The string is non-numeric"
//CDbl(amount)
```

I has no idea what could possibly cause this error.
I can't find any corrupted string in the formatted amounts...

[image: The string is non-numeric]

---

### Questions

1. How could I fix my string amount to make **ToNumber** and **CDbl**
   works fine?
2. How can I convert string amount to decimal number without using **ToNumber** or **CDbl** methods?

If there was only displaying issue, I could use strings as there are, but I need to do some calculations with those amounts so I have to use numeric values there.

---

### Testing unexpected characters in string amount

I prepared specific test to see if any of string amount value has unexpected character inside, but all results of below comparision returned **True**

```
// ---- test ----

amount := Replace(amount, "0", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "1", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "2", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "3", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "4", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "5", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "6", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "7", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "8", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "9", "");
amount := Replace(amount, ".", "");
amount := Replace(amount, "-", "");

// has not unexpected characters
amount = ''

// ---- end test ----
```

---

### Testing convertion

I tested explicit converion of string with point as decimal separator and again error occured (what is strange for me)!

[image]

---

I am using Crystal Reports 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea to solve this problem was to split the string amounts on integer and fractional part, convert them to numbers separately and then add both to get the value.

```
local stringvar amount := Trim({PLD__ITEMS.F_18});
local stringvar intAmount := '0';
local stringvar decAmount := '0';
local numbervar result;
local numbervar decimal;


if amount = ''
    then amount := '0.00'
;

amount := Replace(amount, "(", "-");
amount := Replace(amount, ")", "");
amount := Replace(amount, ",", "");
amount := Replace(amount, " ", "");

if InStr(amount, '.') > 0
    then (
        intAmount := Left(amount, InStr(amount, '.') - 1);
        decAmount := Right(amount, len(amount) - InStr(amount, '.'));
    )
    else intAmount := amount
;

result := ToNumber(intAmount);
decimal := ToNumber(decAmount) / 100;

if result > 0
    then result := result + decimal
    else result := result - decimal
;
```

---

Although this tricky solution works fine, my questions are still open for ideas and/or advices.

#### **updated**

Fix solution for negative numbers - fractional part should be substracted from integer part

Comment: It answers 2nd question - how to make this convertion without using ToNumber and CDbl methods

Answer (score 0):

I found that Crystal using comma as decimal separator. (That was unexpected part for me!)
Below code works fine for me:

```
ToNumber('1,00')
```

Since now the solution was easy:

```
local stringvar amount := Trim({PLD__ITEMS.F_18});

if amount = ''
    then amount := '0.00'
;

amount := Replace(amount, "(", "-");
amount := Replace(amount, ")", "");
amount := Replace(amount, ",", "");
amount := Replace(amount, ".", ",");
amount := Replace(amount, " ", "");

ToNumber(amount)
```

---

Above solves my problem with Crystal Reports report. The values of amounts displayed in Crystal Reports Preview were OK, but when I upload my report to SAP B1 application, the amounts times by 100. So...

[image]

[image]

It looks like convertions is wrong or SAP B1 interpretation of Crystal Report is crashed...

Ugh! What a mess...

So I came back to previous solution with separately converted integer and fractional part, which produce correct amounts on both Crystal Reports preview and SAP B1 application.

Comment: It answers 1st question - how to make ToNumber and CDbl working properly

Comment: CR number formatting is very locale specific.  It looks like your CR is installed in Polish locale, where comma is the defined decimal separator.

Comment: @Krease good point, it may be caused by difference between CR Polish locale and SAP B1 locale, I didn't thought about it... T.Hanks for advice :)